# The OnScroll() of an ImageView encapsulated within a ListView is called multiple times

Tags: android, listview, view, imageview, onscroll

I have a ListView which scrolls vertically and works perfectly.

Each of the elements in the ListView has an ImageView which implements GestureListener that allows users to scroll left/right to see different images.

The problem that I run into is that the OnScroll of the ImageView is called multiple times for every one scroll action performed.

I also noticed that the OnTouchEvent() is called multiple times.

Any idea how I can eliminate the redundant calls of the OnScroll()?

Comment: Sample code would really help - ImageViews don't have an "onScroll" as such. In general an onScroll  should get called only when scrolling completes. Do you see the same behavior on a different android device? Or the emulator?  Assuming you're using [AbsListView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) you could try looking at the `onScrollStateChanged` to wait till you hit `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`

Comment: @hide0...the code is too long to post...I did, however, edit my original question.  I managed to allow ImageView to "listen" to OnScroll by implementing GestureListener.  Thanks for the quick response, btw...Also, I am not using emulator.

Answer (score 0):

[OnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html)'s `onScroll` is called for all relevant [MotionEvents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), so yes it will be called multiple times.

You can either get intelligent with onScroll and explicitly ignore things you don't want to handle, detect back-to-back onScrolls and chain them together (in memory) to build more complex events, OR, if you're lucky and can get away with using a simpler event, use [SimpleOnGestureListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) instead.

Comment: I tried to exam some of the elements within MotionEvents, ie Source, Action and MetaState, and they all have the same value...<scratching my head>